# socket is not working after connection and disconnection time

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

Socket connection working disconnect working I want a share logout event that doesn't work please guide

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
        const query = socket.request._query;
       
        query.status = true;
        io.emit('status', query);
      
        //Socket Disconnect
      
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
          query.status = false;
          
          io.emit('status', query)
        })
      
        socket.on('logout', () => {
            query.status = false;
            io.emit('status', query)
        })
    
        if (query.user_id) {
          socket.join(query.user_id);
        }
      });
```

I am getting nothing on

```
socket.on('logout', () => {
                query.status = false;
                io.emit('status', query)
            })
```

client side

```
   socket.on('logout',function(){ 
    
    console.log("call")
});
why please guide
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server Side it should be

```
socket.on('logout', () => {
     query.status = false;
     io.emit('status', query)
  })
```

Client Side it should be like this

```
socket.emit('logout', (query) => {
     console.log(query)
 })
```